# Do we have a verb expressing that we take out things that are floating on water?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

After I squeeze juice out of an orange into a bowl. Some of the orange pips floats on the orange juice.

If we don't take all the pips out then we have to check for pips when drinking the juice.

Do we have a verb expressing that we take out things that are floating on water using a spoon for example?

For example, **I skim the pips out of the orange juice**

Comment: _Skim_ is only applicable if the pips are floating on the surface (which I'm not sure that they do).

Comment: Most people would strain the juice before serving it...

Comment: You might think about closing some of your questions.  You ask tons of questions, you get lots of help and you don't even bother ever closing them, it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By analogy with angling,  you can say you "fish the pips out the juice".

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fish-out) gives "to pull something out of water or take something out of a bag or pocket", but it can be used for orange juice too.